# expected string or Unicode object, Photo found in django

Tags: python, django, unicode

here i want to read the image from db and apply some operations on my image like noise remove .... and finally i will appy pytesseract to get the text

```
def GetData(request):

    img = Photo.objects.get(id=1)
    #wrapper = FileWrapper(open(img.file))


    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise

    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
    # get b,g,r
    rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
    # switch it to rgb
    # Denoising
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 127, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11,2)
    new_image = cv2.blur(img, (1, 1))
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please, consider edit your question adding information like how you defined your `Photo` class model, what exactly your stacktrace is, etc

Comment: from django.db import models


class Photo(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'photo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'photos'
i want to get the text from photo

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from `cv2.imread(img)` because `imread` take a `string` or `unicode` parameter with the `URI` of the image, but you are using a Django model class which is quite different.

Assuming that your `Photo` class model has an `ImageField` field named `image` you could fix your issue changing

```
img = cv2.imread(img)
```

to something like

```
img = cv2.imread(img.image.url)
```